# Mule 4 : What is the advantage of Remove variable Transformer?

Tags: mule4

Why should we use the remove variable transformer in mule 4?
Because each flow have their own fresh copy of variables when they are called, which means the variables are destroyed by mule itself after the flow completes execution.

To test this theory, I create a Mule flow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="955e025a-379f-49f5-8623-b79b70dedf94" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="remove-variable-exampleFlow" doc:id="7f545df1-b0cf-4b86-bbcc-cba1f9d0a322" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="7d4a9fa8-9760-478a-b75b-0f205ec81ba6" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/create"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log request arrived" doc:id="6e1d8be9-ac47-4f51-8c17-fd114fe583d5" message='#["Request arrived, Value of temp before initilaization : " ++ (vars.temp default "")]'/>
        <set-variable value='#["Random value : " ++ (random()*1000)]' doc:name="Set Temp" doc:id="20de7738-a476-46e6-a442-3a5435092d68" variableName="temp"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="058eaa05-90c9-49c0-b853-9286a01191a0" message='#["Request arrived, Value of temp after initilaization : " ++ vars.temp]'/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

And the result of every time I made the call is  :

```
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Request arrived, Value of temp before initilaization : 
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Request arrived, Value of temp after initilaization : Random value : 588.1040740493614
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Request arrived, Value of temp before initilaization : 
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Request arrived, Value of temp after initilaization : Random value : 582.2399134793665
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Request arrived, Value of temp before initilaization : 
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Request arrived, Value of temp after initilaization : Random value : 743.1259073180681
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Request arrived, Value of temp before initilaization : 
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Request arrived, Value of temp after initilaization : Random value : 526.9686552199496
```

So what is the advantage of using Remove variable transformer in Mule 4?

Answer (score 0):

Advantages make sense in comparing scenarios. In your particular example, there is none, because the flow is too simple and just doesn't need it, and you are not comparing to anything else. However in more complex applications you may have the need to remove a variable before some other operation. For example if you reuse the same variable or if the presence of the variable is used as a flag for a condition.

As you said, it is not used to clear variables when the execution of the flow (event) finishes. That is not needed.